# Requiring scripts is broken when using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, require

Been running into a problem ever since I started using rvm to manage my ruby installation. Whenever I want to require another class I've written, such as `require 'filename'`, I get a `require - no such file to load`  error when I try to run my script. If I switch back to my system ruby using `rvm use system` it works again, but I'm 1.8.2 as my system ruby and some features I want to use in my code are only available in 1.9.*, which I can access through rvm. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a problem with RVM, but a problem with Ruby 1.9 not including '.' in the current path.  For instance, if you are trying to require a library at './lib/file.rb', you can't do

```
require "lib/file"
```

You have to do this:

```
require "./lib/file"
```

Have you tried that syntax for your require?

Comment: I use RVM to manage 4 separate ruby installs (1.8.7, 1.9.2, rbx, and jruby) and have never encountered a situation where this didn't fix require issues I was having.

Comment: If the RVM vs. non-RVM versions are 1.8.x vs 1.9.x, this is definitely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use require_relative

http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html